# The first entry point to Spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I got some problems finding the what is the first line executed in Spark source code
after I run "spark.sql(SQL_QUERY).explain()".

Does anyone have any idea which module/package I could start to look into?
Thanks.

Comment: you can start here https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.scala

Comment: use a debugger, e.g. in InetlliJ. The solution may not be obvious from the source code, as e.g. lazy data-structures are involved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to make spark session or sqlContext  and a registered Temporary table from a `DataFrame` than query on the temporary table like this

```
results = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM people")
names = results.map(lambda p: p.name)
```

Comment: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-getting-started.html

Answer (score 1):

So I guess the first line is this one :
https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.4.4/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/SparkSession.scala#L642

But have already been many lines "executed", specifically to create the `SparkSession`